# Created with py2exe program doesn't work on Windows XP without python

Tags: python, windows-xp, py2exe

I need to use my python program on many different computers with Windows XP and 7, without having to download a Python interpreter. So I create *.exe with py2exe. But when I start it on XP without python installed, I'm getting an error message: «file is corrupt». Is there any way to start it on XP without python?

Here's my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
   windows=[{"script":"linksender.py"}], 
   options={"py2exe": {"includes":[]}}
)
```

Comment: I found the answer. Setup.py must be like this:

from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
   console=['linksender.py'],
   zipfile=None,
   options = {
       "py2exe": {
           'compressed': False,
           'bundle_files': 1,
           }
       },
   )

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your distutils.core.It exist or not.Are you copying the setup.py from the internet?If so ,Copy distutils.core also.
2.Try this(script name=myscript.py):

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=["myscript.py"])
```

3.Your distutils should be something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Distutils',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='Greg Ward',
      author_email='gward@python.net',
      url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
     )
```

**Note:I am not an expert I have used it once before and it worked for me.**